# Getting a spring '15 environment

Tags: visualforce, release, pre-release

I would like to test something on Spring '15 but seems like I already missed the deadline. How can I get a copy of Spring '15 environment? Anything is okay, dev, sandbox or a production org?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a NA1 instance, you should already be on Spring 15. Next set of upgrades coming on Feb 6 and then on Feb 13 and 14. You can find the complete schedule [here](http://blogs.salesforce.com/company/2014/12/8-key-dates-salesforce-spring-15-release.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link to create a Spring '15 developer org:

https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-spring15.jsp

The **spring15** part of the URL will change for each release SalesForce are doing. For Example:

https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-summer15.jsp
https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-winter16.jsp